# Possibiliy to display results SQL query in windows (monitoring purposes)

Tags: monitoring, sql

Case (one example) #1:
Our business application processes documents in the background. Using MS SQL Management Studio I can create/run a query to display results. For example the current queue of documents to print. I can (as administrator) run that query but how can i make this possible that "normal"users can view these results also?

I am thinking to create a monitor screen on the department so everyone can see from a distance what the queue length is. Perhaps i want to add extra information like performance graphs etc, but that's future work.

Does anyone knows a product that makes this possible? The logic behind it is very simple, but i can't find a product that creates this kind of view. I hope someone can point me in a good direction.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the easiest solution would be running some program or script of your own. It's tricky and requires coding knowledge, but it also allows you to do the most customization as well.

For example, utilizing a simple PHP page (ran on a web server), it wouldn't be that complicated (and you could lookup everything from documentation). This is just a made up example and I don't have any server to test it right now though:

```
<?php
    $connection = mssql_connect('servername', 'username', 'password');
    mssql_select_db('database', $connection);

    $result = mssql_query('select count(*) as count from printer_queue;', $connection);
    $data = mssql_fetch_array($result);

    echo 'There are currently ' . $data[count] . 'document(s) in the printer queue.';
?>
```

Of course, the whole formatting etc. could be put into a full fledged/branded HTML page. You could create graphs, etc. it just requires some more programming knowledge.

While this creates a static webpage, you could make it refresh itself once every x minutes (or seconds). Then just show it in a web browser while in fullscreen and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will get into this! Although this will take a lot of time to create (not a coding expert) and for things like graphs i probably need to create a separate DB (or table) to insert the results within a period of my graph.... Still hoping for an application/tool :)

Comment: Just keep it simple for now. Even if it's just some preliminary solution to display any (unformatted) data. It would probably be possible to do similar things with Access for example, but I don't think there's any premade solution where you just throw in your queries and get everything. If you've got issues or question for the coding approach, just ask on stackoverflow.com. And, yes, for some timed graphs you'd most likely have to cache some data in some table/history thing.